# Why Stack overflow error is coming in init

Tags: java, initialization, stack-overflow

I have a code that is causing Stack overflow issue because of uncontrolled recursion happening

```
public class Flaw {

    Flaw() {
        System.out.println("There");
    }

    Flaw obj = new Flaw();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Flaw();
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain it to me that why Flaw() constructor is not printing anything ?

Comment: `Flaw obj = new Flaw();` always creates a new `Flaw` object when the class is instantiated

Answer (score 5):

Before your `Flaw` constructor's body can be executed (which would execute your `println` statement), the instance variables of your class are initialized. In your case, that means the `Flaw obj=new Flaw();` variable, which creates another `Flaw` instance, triggering another constructor call, and so on...

An infinite chain of constructor calls leads to `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
public class Flaw {

    Flaw() {
        System.out.println("There");
    }

    Flaw obj = new Flaw();
}
```

is the same as this:

```
public class Flaw {

    Flaw() {
        System.out.println("There");
    }

    Flaw obj;

    {
      obj = new Flaw();
    }
}
```

Instance initializers get inserted in between the invocation of the superclass' constructor, and the rest of the constructor body. So it's equivalent to this:

```
public class Flaw {
    Flaw obj;

    Flaw() {
        // Invocation of superclass constructor.
        super();

        // Inlined instance initializer.
        obj = new Flaw();

        // Rest of constructor body.
        System.out.println("There");
    }
}
```

You invoke the constructor of `Flaw` from the constructor of `Flaw`, prior to printing anything. That invokes the constructor of `Flaw`, which  invokes the constructor of `Flaw`, which  invokes the constructor of `Flaw`, ec.